# JPA , sorting query by collection last date valued property

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have two entities in my project with hibernate relation

```
@Entity
class IssueEntity {

@OneToMany
List<CorrespondenceEntity> correspondenceList;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class CorrespondenceEntity {

Date modifyDate;

@ManyToOne
IssueEntity issue;
}
```

It is possible to create query using JPQL which get IssueEntity from IssueRepository ordering by last (max) date of property contained in collection "correspondenceList" -  "modifyDate"

Comment: yes it is.. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I try to use other SELECT in AND clause, but spelling was not correct,
and somewhere i find solution to use custom index with index(x) jpql method, but without success

Comment: ok so we get IssueEntity with correspondence with max(modifiedDate) and then we order all those IssueEntity's by .. modifiedDate again? Would be good if you add the native sql query to clear the air

Comment: Native query not support pageable object, which i need to use in my case

Comment: You got a backreference, so it's easier to the query from the CorrespondenceRepository: `SELECT DISTINCT c.issue FROM CorrespondenceEntity c ORDER BY c.modifyDate`

Comment: @luafanti,
Do you use Spring Data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know the question was

> It is (or Is it) possible to create query using JPQL

Anyway

> JPA , sorting query by collection last date valued property

is possible with annotation `@OrderBy`, like

```
@OneToMany
@OrderBy("modifyDate DESC") // or "modifyDate ASC" whatever suits better
List<CorrespondenceEntity> correspondenceList;
```

See [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html)

Comment: Yes, it is first step to resolve my case, but I still don't find solution to get first element of collection (last "modifyDate" of CorrespondenceEntity after ordering by annotation) and use it in  "order by"  JPQL clause at  IssueEntity



`@Query(value ="SELECT i FROM IssueEntity i 
        LEFT JOIN i.correspondenceList co
        ORDER BY  // get first element of collection and value of modifyDate // " )`

Comment: Ok, seems that I did not fully understand your question. Maybe you should add the JPQL as you have it now to the question, preferably few lines of sample data and what the query should return from that sample data. `CorrespondenceEntity` with he latest `modifyDate` in the list is obviously the one you get with `correspondenceList.get(0)` assuming not empty.

Comment: @luafanti btw: is it possible to use CriteriaQuery instead?

Comment: Maybe it is possible, like I see crriteriaQuery support pageable, which in my case is necessary